# Привязка данных к компонентам winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

Добрый день. В первый раз столкнулся с такой проблемой: имеется коллекция `ObservableCollection<string>`, которая была передана как источник данных для двух комбо-боксов.

```
ObservableCollection<string> list = new ObservableCollection<string>();

list.Add("Test String First");
list.Add("Test String Second");

cmbFirst.DataSource = list;
cmbSecond.DataSource = list;
```

Если в окне я выбираю строку в первом комбо-боксе, то эта же строка выбирается и во втором комбо-боксе. Каким образом можно отключить данную "привязку"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите разные `BindingSource` для ваших выпадающих списков

```
cmbFirst.DataSource = new BindingSource(list, null);
cmbSecond.DataSource = new BindingSource(list, null);
```